# how to execute function after validation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a form and validation for it. The problem is that I don't know how to check if the fields are filled in correctly and then send. How can I submit after all fields are filled in correctly?

```js
const addBanksFunc = () => {
  addBankButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
  });
};

const setError = (element, message) => {...};

const setSuccess = (element) => {...};

const checkInputs = () => {
  if (bankName.value === "") {
    setError(bankName, "Some text");
  } else {
    setSuccess(bankName);
  }

  if (interestRate.value === "") {
    setError(interestRate, "Some text");
  } else {
    setSuccess(interestRate);
  }

  if (maximumLoan.value === "") {
    setError(maximumLoan, "Some text");
  } else {
    setSuccess(maximumLoan);
  }

  if (minimumDownPayment.value === "") {
    setError(minimumDownPayment, "Some text");
  } else {
    setSuccess(minimumDownPayment);
  }

  if (loanTerm.value === "") {
    setError(loanTerm, "Some text");
  } else {
    setSuccess(loanTerm);
  }
};
```

Comment: Instead of listening to the `click` event on the button, listen form the `submit` event on your `<form>`. Whenever your form is validated, select the form element and call [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `checkInputs` signature, make it return true (form is valid) or false.

```
const checkInputs = () => {
  if (bankName.value === "") {
    setError(bankName, "Some text");
    return false;
  } else {
    setSuccess(bankName);
  }

  if (interestRate.value === "") {
    setError(interestRate, "Some text");
    return false;
  } else {
    setSuccess(interestRate);
  }
  ...

 return true;
}
```

and

```
const addBanksFunc = () => {
  addBankButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const isFormValid = checkInputs();
    if (isFormValid) {
        // submit the form here
    }
  });
};
```

Im actually not really sure about how to `// submit the form` with button onClick listener, probably it is better to use something like

```
orderForm.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //some code here
    this.submit();
})
```

UPD: Due to comment question

Im not sure about what is the logic inside `setError` method you have, but if originaly you had it showing errors for all the fields -

```
const checkInputs = () => {
  let result = true;
  if (bankName.value === "") {
    setError(bankName, "Some text");
    result = false;
  } else {
    setSuccess(bankName);
  }

  if (interestRate.value === "") {
    setError(interestRate, "Some text");
    result = false;
  } else {
    setSuccess(interestRate);
  }
  ...

 return result;
}
```

Usually im using native attributes form validation with `required` or `pattern` or `type` or whatever attributes and then applying additional logical validation in same way you doing it.

Comment: Your variant validates one by one. When you click on the button, the first field is validated. After entering the data into it and pressing the button again, the following is validated. How can I validate all fields at once?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` or `class` for the form you want to submit.
Lets say you have put an id="myForm" to the for you want to submit.

After all the checks, use the below code to submit the form through code.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Note: put the submit button outside the form to avoid auto submission without the checks.

Answer (score 0):

Form element has checkValidity function documented over [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity),

Moreover you can create onSubmitHandler like this:

```js
function handleSubmitHandler(event){
     
      const form = document.getElementById('form')
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        alert('Validation field')
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        return
      }
      const formData = new FormData(form)
      const formProps = Object.fromEntries(formData)
      console.log('FORM DATA---', formProps)
      // DO YOU LOGIC HERE AND THEN USE
      form.submit()
      
   }
   
   
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", handleSubmitHandler);
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<Form id="form" method="POST" >
<input required name="name" />
<button id="button" variant="success" type="button">
  Submit
</button>
</Form>
```

More On Form Validation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Thanks